# How to track changes in array through all the tabs?

Tags: android

I have MainActivity.java and 3 tabs via tabbed activity (InfoActivity, PlotActivity, MapActivity).
In MainActivity.java I'm getting some information (like GPS, SignalStrength, etc.) to array and I want to use these data in all activities. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `TabActivity`, it has been deprecated a long time ago. Instead use a `BottomNavigationView` with `Fragment`'s. Then you can use a shared `ViewModel` scoped to your `Activity` to share data.

First setup the [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) and turn your info, plot and map activities into fragments. Then read up on how to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=CjwKCAjwiaX8BRBZEiwAQQxGx6AvppEP-IOi3wXa7xZfu4FGH8vlyhoxHbuKZ_lgbMc4sp2t5H5MTxoCDz8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). There's a whole [section](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=CjwKCAjwiaX8BRBZEiwAQQxGx6AvppEP-IOi3wXa7xZfu4FGH8vlyhoxHbuKZ_lgbMc4sp2t5H5MTxoCDz8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#sharing) on how to share data between your fragments.

Comment: So, in case I already have info, plot and map activities as a fragments it will not be hard to re-code them with BottomNavigationView?

Comment: Yes, it should be fairly straightforward. Make sure to use the androidx libraries: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx, e.g. replace TabActivity with the androidx.Activity.